Export Data AS (Excel Or CSV) From The PowerBI Table From the Published Report
I am stuck in the middle of somewhere if someone can help me with that it would be really helpful.
I have created several dashboards in powerBI and published them to service, but the issue is some of the visuals are showing the Export Data Button, and some tables are showing only the copy as image option, can someone please explain or help me export data from the visual.

This export data button I need in my visual.
